# I have error in running dataset from Kaggle, it worked on my MacBook but it couldn't be runed in Windows10

Tags: python, dataset, artificial-intelligence, kaggle, error-code

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTjLv.png)

I am trying to run a code from Kaggle in my windows10 laptop, but I receive error message in reading the images and I don't know why. This is the link of the dataset I used in PyCharm from Kaggle: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/airbusgeo/airbus-aircrafts-sample-dataset/code I was expecting the code to be runed.